# Import Spray+Akka template in Eclipse scala

Tags: scala, akka, spray

I'm new in a Spray + Akka + project and I've already downloaded the spray-template in this page: https://github.com/spray/spray-template/tree/on_spray-can_1.2.

That template compiles with de sbt but I want to work with it in my Scala Eclipse.

¿How can I do that? ¿Where can I find spray libraries in order to add them to my Akka-project in Eclipse?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: See the `sbteclipse` sbt plugin: https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse 

If you install it globally you can type `eclipse` in any sbt project and it will create the needed project metadata for eclipse.